# How to extend ICU collation with custom rules in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sorting, collation, icu

I want to use ICU collations in SQLite for sorting the results of SQL queries. I have customized collation rules which I want to load on top of the default rules for a specific locale. So I first want to load the collation for a locale and then I want to load the customized collation which should extend, but not replace the previously loaded collation.

How can I achieve this with SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no mechanism to derive one collation from another.

Just install your own custom collation (you can use SQLite's ICU collation code as template), and call the appropriate functions from the ICU libray when needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your proposal correctly. My main target is to have the rules of the language specific default collations (e.g. English, German etc.) plus my own custom rules. When should I call ICU functions directly?

Comment: In your own implementation. How exactly this is to be done depends on how you want to change the rules.